# Trying to convert python code to ruby code

Tags: python, ruby

Here's the python code:

```
with open('config.json') as json_data_file:
       configuration = json.load(json_data_file)
       access_token=configuration["canvas"]["access_token"]
       baseUrl="https://"+configuration["canvas"]["host"]+"/api/v1/courses/"

header = {'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + access_token}
```

I'm trying to write some code in ruby that does the exact same thing as the python code above. This is how I wrote it:

```
File.open("config.json") {|json_data_file|
  configuration = json.load(json_data_file)
  access_token=configuration["canvas"]["access_token"]
  baseUrl="https://"+configuration["canvas"]["host"]+"/api/v1/courses/"
}

header = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token}
```

Is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: Is anything happening that suggests that it's _not_ the correct way of doing it?

Comment: As of now, I can't really test it because I need a testing environment for the Canvas LMS. I have a colleague who has already set up a testing environment, but I want to make sure it's correct before I can send it to him for testing.

Answer (score 2):

It's simpler than that. You use [IO#read](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/IO.html#method-c-read) to return the file content as a string and then you use [JSON.parse](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-parse) to convert JSON to a Ruby structure.

Say this is your `config.json` file:

```
{
  "canvas": {
    "access_token": "i like pie",
    "host": "ilikepie.com"
  }
}
```

And to access information from `config.json` in Ruby code:

```rb
# You need to require JSON
require 'json'

config_file = File.read('config.json')
config_hash = JSON.parse(config_file)

# Now you can access everything from `config_hash`
access_token = config_hash['canvas']['access_token'] # => 'i like pie'
host = config_hash['canvas']['host'] # => 'ilikepie.com'
```

Your final Ruby code should look something like this:

```rb
require 'json'

config = JSON.parse(File.read('config.json'))

access_token = config['canvas']['access_token']
host = config['canvas']['host']

# Use snake case in Ruby scripts. Also, use string interpolation, it's much clearer.
base_url = "https://#{host}/api/v1/courses/" # => 'https://ilikepie.com/api/v1/courses/'
```

Comment: When I said "use snake case in Ruby scripts" I didn't mean you must use it, but you should.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try when I have a testing environment up and running. But what about the ruby code that I wrote? Is that incorrect?

Comment: @BobK It is. First: you did not `require 'json'`. Second: `json.load` does not exist, it should be `JSON`, all capitals. Third: the `load` method (https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-load) converts a Ruby structure to JSON and not JSON to a Ruby structure (that's `JSON.parse` job). Fourth: `access_token` and `baseUrl` are local to the block associated with `File.open`. That means you won't be able to access them once you exit the block.

Comment: I would be glad to add examples to my answer to show why it is incorrect.

Comment: I actually added a line to my python code above. It defines a header for the Rest API. Unfortunately I don't know the Ruby equivalent of it.